# Can I set the tag property on a UIView subclass?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I've got a UIView subclass called CardView, and created an instance like so:

```
CardView *newCard = [[CardView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)];
```

And then I've tried to set the view's tag like this:

```
newCard.tag = 1;
```

But that doesn't seem to be actually setting the tag for that view. If I set a breakpoint around there, and do

```
po newCard.tag
```

in the debugger, it says

```
error: property 'tag' not found on object of type 'CardView *'
```

Shouldn't I be getting a tag property as part of the UIView subclass?

Comment: Can you post your .h of CardView please ? Yes you should be getting the tag property as part of your subclass

Comment: Just a long shot, but have you tried with the alternative `[newCard setTag:1];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The debugger console does not understand the Objective C property syntax. Instead, do this in the source file:

```
NSLog(@"%d", newCard.tag);
```

and you'll see it in the console.

The debugger understands methods though, although it gets confused about datatypes. This debugger command would work:

```
p (int)[newCard tag]
```

That's about as objective as GDB gets.

Comment: Ooohhh, that totally did the trick (casting as int). It is indeed storing the tag correctly. Thanks!